# Can two servers from different domains subscribe for events from APNS?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am using a third party service for pushing remote notifications to my iOS clients. Therefore the third party has my app certificate.

However, this service does not implement the handling for Apple Feedback Service. So I want to implement the feedback service on my end.

Can I connect to the Feedback Service from a server in different domain using the same app certificate?

Will Apple object if the same app certificate is being used from two different domains?

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a problem in connecting to APNS servers with the same certificate from different domains. But if you are concerned about doing that, you can create two push certificates for your app and use a different certificate for the Feedback Service.

That said, a push provider that doesn't handle something as besic as the Feedback Service is a push provider I'd stop using. Either find a decent push provider that handles the Feedback too, or handle the push + the Feedback yourself (if you have to handle the Feedback yourself, it means you are probably managing the DB of device tokens and your 3rd party service doesn't do much anyway).

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using the same SSL certificate that you used for pushing notifications as well, it should not be an issue. Here's the documentation- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html . However, if the end goal is to remove those devices from the list of devices to send PN to, then this won't serve your purpose I guess, since you mentioned that handling PN for you is done by a 3rd party provider- you can not manually send them a list of device ids to be removed from their list everyday..:D. Better to change your APNs provider or do it yourself.